# std::istream does not call xsgetn() on read operations?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, std

I want to be notified when a file associated with a std::istream is read from using the istream and the same with an ostream being written to. With this in mind I decided to try deriving my own std::basic_filebuf, and just to experiment I tried to override the xsgetn() and xsputn() functions so that they would output to the console before calling the parent implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

class MyFileBuff : public std::filebuf
{
public:
    std::streamsize xsgetn(char_type* s, std::streamsize count) override
    {
        std::cout << "using my xsgetn()" << std::endl;
        return std::filebuf::xsgetn(s, count);
    }

    std::streamsize xsputn(const char_type* s, std::streamsize count) override
    {
        std::cout << "using my xsputn()" << std::endl;
        return std::filebuf::xsputn(s, count);
    }

    using std::filebuf::basic_filebuf;
};



int main()
{
    //open file
    FILE* filePtr{ nullptr };
    fopen_s(&filePtr, "text.txt", "w+");

    //associate file with instance of custom std:filebuff
    MyFileBuff fileBuff(filePtr);

    //initalize i/o streams with file buffer
    std::istream myIStream(&fileBuff);
    std::ostream myOStream(&fileBuff);

    //output to file
    myOStream << "hello world" << std::endl;


    const short buffSize{ 1024 };
    char buff[buffSize];
    myIStream.seekg(0);
    //read from file
    myIStream.getline(buff, buffSize);

    //output what was read to console
    std::cout << buff << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
> using my xsputn()
> hello world
```

As you can see, my override of `xsputn()` is called on the write operation. But despite the read operation completing successfully, my override of `xsgetn()` is never called. I would like help understanding why.

I have also tried overloading the `std::basic_filebuf::uflow()` and `std::basic_filebuf::underflow()` functions in a similar manner and they do successfully output to the console when the `istream` is read, but I don't understand why `xsgetn()` never gets called?

Comment: A stream implementation may call `xsgetn` and `xsputn` but doesn't have to.

Comment: @n.m.  Is there a guaranteed way to intercept all read/write operations that a std::i/ostream does on a std::streambuf?  Perhaps overriding the std::streambuf::overflow() std::streambuf::underflow() funcitons?

Comment: Scratch that, I don't think there is any guarantee.

Comment: @n.m. C++ streams... I upvoted this question because it looks easy on the surface, but C++ streams are not. :-) SO doesn't have that many answers digging deep into streams. I'd like one or two more.